# Next claim is true or not?

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory

If $\lim_{\lambda \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(\sup_{s \le t}|M_s|>\lambda)=0$,then $\mathbb{E}[|M_t|:\sup_{s\le t}|M_s| \ge \lambda]=0$.
This proposition is true or not? In my  intuitively, it is true. Because conditional's measure will banish. But I cannot prove it. Please help me.

Comment: Poor measure, it will be banished.

Comment: Take $M_s=X$ for all $s$, where $X$ is some random variable.   Now your question significantly simplifies. Can you answer it?

Comment: If X is bounded, this proof is very easy. But now, X isn't necessarily bounded. It is difficult for me to prove it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Poor measure. And I found out about poor measure, but I didn't find literature related to Poor measure. Would you tell me literature related to poor measure, please.

Answer (score 0):

I solved.

If $\lim \mathbb{E}[|M_t|:\sup_{s \le t}|M_s| \ge \lambda] \neq 0$, there exists $\epsilon$ such that $\mathbb{E}[|M_t|:\sup_{s \le t}|M_s| \ge \lambda]> \epsilon$($\forall \lambda>0$).And we can create step function $X=\sum_{k=1}^m a_k \mathbb{1}_{A_k}$ such that $X \ge |M_t|$. So, $\epsilon <\mathbb{E}[|M_t|:\sup_{s \le t}|M_s| \ge \lambda] \le \mathbb{E}[X:\sup_{s \le t}|M_s| \ge \lambda]=\sum a_k \mathbb{P}(A_k \cap B_{\lambda}) \le \sum a_k \mathbb{P}(B_\lambda)$ (where $B_{\lambda}:=\{\sup |M_s|\ge \lambda\}$). Thus we can gain $\mathbb{P}(B_\lambda)>\frac{\epsilon}{\sum a_k}$ ($\forall \lambda$).This means contradiction.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Given: $\lim_{\lambda \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(\sup_{s \le t}|M_s|>\lambda)=0$

Claim: $M_s < \lambda\quad \forall s$

Proof: Consider the sequence $\{M_i\}$. Let $M_{s'}$ be the first time the sequence is greater than $\lambda$. Then $\forall s \geq s'$, $\sup_{s \le t}|M_s|>\lambda$, and thus $\mathbb{P}(\sup_{s \le t}|M_s|>\lambda)>0$ contradicting the assumption.

---

Now for the second part, consider the set $\{|M_t|:\sup_{s\le t}|M_s| \ge \lambda\}$. This is an empty set based on what we just proved. Expectation of empty set is not defined (so I think the answer is that it is not defined, not 0).